# Spell checker not detecting spelling errors

Tags: spellchecker

The spell checker on my companies SharePoint site seems to not be working correctly. When we type a spelling error, i.e. customre, then click the Spell checker it says no spelling errors are found, but if you keep clicking it after 5+ times it seems to find the error.

Is there a way to make this work on the first click as it's causing a lot of our business areas to add incorrect content?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your server logs?  It sounds very similar to a problem that I'm experiencing & haven't gotten an answer for yet.

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/c0df8ea8-084d-43c9-be24-1383f41bda8a) is a thread that I found that is similar.

Comment: We have no access to our server logs, they locked that down to us. That level of access only lays with our support team.

Comment: Can you run Fiddler on your workstation?  When the spell check incorrectly says "No spelling errors found", I noticed that Fiddler would actually show the HTTP response contained the error.   It would be interesting to see if you get the same result.